# What's the name of this stochastic process?

Tags: probability

I heard about it sometime somewhere and want to read about it now, but I can't recall what the name is:

Start with $a_1 = \ldots =a_n=1$. Choose a number between 1 and $n$ with probability $a_i/(a_1+ \ldots + a_n)$ to choose $i$. If $i_0$ is the number chosen, increase $a_i$ by 1 and now choose another number and so on indefinitely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For this process and a substantial generalization, see [this](http://www.combinatorics.net/aoc/toc/v7n2/Chung/7_2_141.pdf).
The case $p=0$ and $\gamma = 1$ corresponds to the process you described.

Comment: Just for the record the link says that this is called the Polya urn process.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the pointer, Shai Covo. The name of this specific process is [preferential attachment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preferential_attachment).